# GLM model specification in distribution and link function for fractional (percentage) response data

Tags: generalized-linear-model, binomial-distribution, stata, proportion, link-function

I have some aggregated data.

```
Indep.   Dep.    N
1.3      78%     23
1.2      67%     20
```

Note that both the independent and dependent variables are aggregated by location, and I don't have individual data that contains both independent and dependent variables. Namely, indep. var. came from one data source, and dep. var. came from another independent data source.

Independent variable is the average of individual scores (ranging from -1 to +1), while dependent variable is the percent of individual answered "yes" (as supposed to answering "No"). N is the number of people providing the answer to dependent variable in that region.

I would like to model it using generalized linear model (glm), but unsure if I have specified the distribution and link function correctly. Note: I have also modeled it via grouped logistic regression and beta regression. Significance (5%) was found in both grouped logistic regression and beta regression result, so I assume the correct glm model will likely also give significant result.

First for the GLM, I tried Gaussian distribution and logit function

```
glm howlong avg_sent_1 if lown_state==0, family(gaussian) link(logit)
```

I do get significant result with

```
Coef. = -5.167418, and P>|z| =  0.033
```

These results matched the ones in grouped logistic regression and beta regression results. Though I am not sure if Gaussian is the right distribution, so I tried binomial distribution, and the results as follows:

```
glm howlong avg_sent_1 if lown_state==0, family(binomial) link(logit)
note: howlong has noninteger values
Coef. =  -5.419125, and P>|z| =  0.837
```

Question 1) Which GLM specification is the right one?

Question 2) Is there any way I can incorporate N as weight?

Comment: Are the percentages ratios of *counts*  or are they continuous fractions?

Comment: This is largely a Stata question, and to that extent partly off-topic here. You need to specify frequency weights, `family(binomial) vce(robust)` and to ensure that you are presenting the dependent variable as a proportion between 0 and 1.

Comment: Hi Nick, I am not familiar with fractional response analysis, could you please tell me how I can specify frequency weight, and how to ensure I am presenting the dependent variable as between 0 and 1? Will this line "glm howlong avg_sent_1 if lown_state==0, family(binomial) vce(robust)" suffice?

Comment: I agreed this is closely tied to Stata, but it's not solely about Stata, I am also inquiring about why GLM (with binomial distribution and robust estimators) failed to find significance while beta regression and grouped logistic regression did. Which is a better analytical approach?